# Portmanteau lemma: Prove that 4 implies 2

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

If lim inf $E[f(X_n)] \geq E[f(X)]$ for any non-negative, continuous function $f(.)$ then $E[g(X_n)]=E[g(X)]$ for all bounded, continuous functions $g(.)$., where $X_n$ define a sequence of bounded probability measures.

The question talks about the version in Asymptotic Statistics in A.W. van der Vaart. I know how to go from 1 to 4 that is prove lim inf $E[f(X_n)] \geq E[f(X)]$ for any non-negative, continuous function $f(.)$ if we have weak convergence using Fatou's Lemma. I am unsure how to show any of the other statements if 4 holds.

Comment: You don't seem to have written a question we can answer.  You told us where to find it, but that's not much use :)

Comment: I have doubts about the fact that $X_n$ is a probability measure, or if it is then I don't know what $E[f(X_n)]$ is (my guess would have been expectation and then $X_n$ is a random variable with some probability measure right ?).

Comment: @P.Quinton yes as I wrote it defines a probability, the Lesbegue Stieltjes measure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f$ be any bounded continuous function and $M$ be its supremum. Then $M-f$ is a non-negative continous function so $\lim \inf E(M-f(X_n)) \geq E(M-f(X))$. Cancelling $M$ we get $\lim \sup Ef(X_n) \leq Ef(X)$. Changing $f$ to $-f$ we get $\lim \inf Ef(X_n) \geq Ef(X)$. Hence $\lim Ef(X_n)=Ef(X)$.