# Portmanteau Lemma -- Prove that 2 implies 4

Tags: real-analysis, probability, weak-convergence

This is the inverse of the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3250325/portmanteau-lemma-prove-that-4-implies-2). I am also reading the book *Asymptotic Statistics* by Van der Vaart, and I want a sketch for the proof for Lemma 2.2 (Page 6).

The Lemma states if $\mathbb{E}f(X_n)\to \mathbb{E}f(X)$ for all bounded, continuous functions $f$, then $\liminf \mathbb{E}f(X_n)\ge \mathbb{E}f(X)$ for all nonnegative, countinuous functions $f$.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ be  a non-negative continuous function, $N$ be a positive integer and $g_N=\min \{f,N\}$. Then $g$ is a bounded continuous function, so $Eg(X_n) \to Eg(X)$. But $Eg(X_n) \leq Ef(X_n)$. Hence $\lim \inf Ef(X_n) \geq \lim \inf Eg(X_n) =\lim Eg(X_n)=Eg(X)$. This is true for every $N$. $Eg(X) \to Ef(X)$ as $N \to \infty$ by Monotone Convergence Theorem. Hence $\lim \inf Ef(X_n) \geq Ef(X)$.